# boost::spirit optional parsing into a fusion adapted structure

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

If there's a structure

```
struct price
{
   int chicken;
   int cow;
   bool in_stock;
   std::string place;
};
```

which is adapted using boost::fusion.
If there's a need to parse it, but optionally for in_stock and place. e.g.

```
template <typename it, typename skipper = qi::space_type>
struct p : qi::grammar<it, price(), skipper>
{
    p() : p::base_type(p_instance)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        psr %= int_ > int_ > -bool_ > -('"' > char_ % ',' > '"');
    }
  private:
      qi::rule<it,price(),skipper> limit;
};
```

However, this does not work. There's an exception thrown, if an input is `"2 3 \"Chili\""`.
What is a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Firstly

I guess you're having a few too many `>` expectation points, which could/should be `>>` sequence operators.

I'd say, make your grammar more explicit, e.g. by saying

```
bool_ | attr(false)
```

to ensure that if `bool_` fails, there will be a resulting attribute value of `false` exposed. This way, the exposed attribute is `bool`, instead of `boost::optional<bool>`, which is more compatible with the target struct (`price`).

Demo:

```
template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, price(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        in_stock = bool_ | attr(false);
        start    = int_ > int_ > in_stock > -('"' >> char_ % ',' > '"');
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, price(), Skipper> start;
    qi::rule<It, bool()> in_stock;
};
```

## Secondly

Then,

```
('"' > char_ % ',' > '"')
```

will only ever match string like `"a"`, `"b,c,d"` etc. If you wanted `"Chili"` to parse, you should probably change it to something like:

```
    place    = '"' >> *~char_('"') > '"';
    start    = int_ > int_ > in_stock > (place | attr(""));
```

Which means parse any string delimited by `'"'` (`~char_("abc)` means: *any char except [abc]*).

## Sample solution

Here's a full demonstration showing:

- Fusion adaptation of the struct
- the above adjusted grammar
- using BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG to debug
- catching `qi::expectation_failure` to print diagnostics on parse failure
- using Spirit Karma to print the result of parsing in human readable form

Output of test program listed below:

### Code

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

struct price
{
    int chicken;
    int cow;
    bool in_stock;
    std::string place;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(price, 
        (int, chicken)
        (int, cow)
        (bool, in_stock)
        (std::string, place))

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, price(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        in_stock = bool_ | attr(false);
#if 0
        start    = int_ > int_ > in_stock > -('"' >> char_ % ',' > '"');
#else
        place    = '"' >> *~char_('"') > '"';
        start    = int_ > int_ > in_stock > (place | attr(""));
#endif

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(start);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(place);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(in_stock);
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, price(), Skipper> start;
    //
    qi::rule<It, bool()>            in_stock;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()>     place; // no skipper
};

bool doParse(const std::string& input)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

    parser<It, qi::space_type> p;
    price data;

    try
    {
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,data);
        if (ok)   
        {
            std::cout << "parse success: '" << input << "'\n";
            std::cout << "data: " << karma::format_delimited(karma::eps <<
                    "chicken:"  << karma::int_  << 
                    "cow:"      << karma::int_  << 
                    "in_stock:" << karma::bool_ << 
                    "place:"    << karma::auto_,
                    " ", data) << "\n";
        }
        else      std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

        if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
        return ok;
    } catch(const qi::expectation_failure<It>& e)
    {
        std::string frag(e.first, e.last);
        std::cerr << e.what() << "'" << frag << "'\n";
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    doParse("1 2 true \"a,b,c,d,e,f\"");
    doParse("3 4 \"a,b,c,d,e,f\"");
    doParse("5 6");
    doParse("7 8 false");
}
```

### Output

```
<start>
  <try>1 2 true "a,b,c,d,e,</try>
  <in_stock>
    <try>true "a,b,c,d,e,f"</try>
    <success> "a,b,c,d,e,f"</success>
    <attributes>[1]</attributes>
  </in_stock>
  <place>
    <try>"a,b,c,d,e,f"</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[a, ,, b, ,, c, ,, d, ,, e, ,, f]]</attributes>
  </place>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[1, 2, 1, [a, ,, b, ,, c, ,, d, ,, e, ,, f]]]</attributes>
</start>
parse success: '1 2 true "a,b,c,d,e,f"'
data:  chicken: 1 cow: 2 in_stock: true place: a,b,c,d,e,f 
<start>
  <try>3 4 "a,b,c,d,e,f"</try>
  <in_stock>
    <try>"a,b,c,d,e,f"</try>
    <success>"a,b,c,d,e,f"</success>
    <attributes>[0]</attributes>
  </in_stock>
  <place>
    <try>"a,b,c,d,e,f"</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[a, ,, b, ,, c, ,, d, ,, e, ,, f]]</attributes>
  </place>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[3, 4, 0, [a, ,, b, ,, c, ,, d, ,, e, ,, f]]]</attributes>
</start>
parse success: '3 4 "a,b,c,d,e,f"'
data:  chicken: 3 cow: 4 in_stock: false place: a,b,c,d,e,f 
<start>
  <try>5 6</try>
  <in_stock>
    <try></try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[0]</attributes>
  </in_stock>
  <place>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </place>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[5, 6, 0, []]]</attributes>
</start>
parse success: '5 6'
data:  chicken: 5 cow: 6 in_stock: false place:  
<start>
  <try>7 8 false</try>
  <in_stock>
    <try>false</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[0]</attributes>
  </in_stock>
  <place>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </place>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[7, 8, 0, []]]</attributes>
</start>
parse success: '7 8 false'
data:  chicken: 7 cow: 8 in_stock: false place:
```

Comment: Do you know what's a difference between setting a rule and setting a grammar by phoenix ref. as a start of a grammar?

Comment: There's no major difference except, likely, for debugging facilities, error handling facilities, and potentially parser context. I'm thinking of these on the fly, though. See the difference between the two ***Concepts*** in the documentation **[section on non-terminals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal.html)**. Basically, rules provide a **[much richer interface](http://tinyurl.com/rule-expression-semantics)** than Grammars, and Grammars are intended for modularization.

Comment: I am interested in debugging and exceptions. There's an exception thrown, which is not caught (post #1), also spirit debugger does not enable debugging (no defaut handler is defined for grammar).

Comment: What are you trying to tell me? I think my example code covered all of those. If you got stuck with something else this time, you might want to open a new question.

Comment: There's other type of exception thrown when a grammar is a start of a grammar which fails. It was uncaught.

Comment: @user2496553 I'm sure it's the English language barrier, but I don't get it. There's no other exception in my code. If _you_ have one, post a new question about it. Don't forget to mention _what kind of exception_ is thrown. Till, then, good luck (I have no idea what you mean by "a grammar is a start of a grammar (which fails))

Comment: No, not in your post. The example mentioned in the previous commentary is not posted here. e.g. struct some_grammar is defined inheriting spirit's grammar. Inside some_grammar the starting point of parsing is a grammar, not a rule.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33212/discussion-between-user2496553-and-sehe)